# Is it possible to prevent slow first query with hibernate, c3p0 and Tomcat?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, c3p0

I'm using `hibernate` with `c3p0` on `Tomcat`. The very first query is slow, which is to be expected while both `hibernate` and the connection pool are initialized.

But what we're seeing it that after a time of inactivity the first query is slow once again. Is it possible to prevent it?

Here's my configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/antiques</property>        
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">myschema</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>   
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property> 
<property name="c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
```

Comment: You should EXPLAIN PLAN on your queries and look for TABLE SCAN.  You should profile your code to see where and why things are slow.  Don't assume that you know.

Comment: @duffymo I did. There are no table scans and we're still in development so the tables are very small (10-50 rows.) The slowness happens only for the first query while all subsequent ones are very fast.

Comment: I'd wonder if generated SQL and PreparedStatements are being cached.  Perhaps they aren't.  The cost of PreparedStatements comes in when you parse SQL and validate it against the existing schema.  It should only be done once and stored.  I'm not sure if the MySQL driver class caches PreparedStatements.